# How do you get date time format in an Ajax-call?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-ui

I will create a Excel with the "myOrder" and a suffix of the current date.
How do you get a filename with a format of "yyyyMMddhhmmss" By example: "20220704073533"?

```
   $.ajax({
        url: kendo.format('@(Server.UrlDecode(Url.Action("myExcel", "NewOrder", new { orderKeys = "{0}" })))', ids.join()),
        method: 'POST',
        xhrFields: {
            responseType: 'blob'
        },
        success: function (data) {
            var a = document.createElement('a');
            var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);
            a.href = url;
            a.download = 'myOrder' + date().format('yyyyMMddhhmmss') + '.xlsx';
            document.body.append(a);
            a.click();
            a.remove();
            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
        }

    });
```

Comment: what is the `date` variable, does it have a `.format` method? should the date be the local date or UTC? in UTC if date is a Date ... `.toISOString().replace(/\D/g, '').substring(0,14)`

Comment: for local time - `new Intl.DateTimeFormat('fr-ca', {dateStyle:'short', timeStyle: 'medium'}).format(date).replace(/\D+/g, '')`

Comment: date or datetime. Is there something like DateTime?

Comment: Javascript has `Date` type - don't tell me you don't even know what the `date` variable is!

Comment: Sorry JavaScript has many secrets for me. But I've solved the problem and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written a function like this

```
function FormatDateTime() {

    var dateObj = new Date();

    var month = (dateObj.getUTCMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, "0");      
    var day = dateObj.getUTCDate().toString().padStart(2, "0");
    var year = dateObj.getUTCFullYear().toString().padStart(4, "0");
    var hours = dateObj.getUTCHours().toString().padStart(2, "0");
    var minutes = dateObj.getUTCMinutes().toString().padStart(2, "0");
    var seconds = dateObj.getUTCSeconds().toString().padStart(2, "0");

    var dateStr = year + month + day + hours + minutes + seconds;

    return dateStr;
}
```

And then...

```
<script src="~/Scripts/FormatDateTime.js"></script>

var dateStr = FormatDateTime();
```

And in the Ajax-call:

```
 a.download = 'myOrder' + dateStr + '.xlsx';
```

And that works for me.